# Quantity problem in Cart

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, price, quantity

I've purchased **wholesale packaged product extension** to use it on my website.
I am not sure if it is because of this extension, but when a customer orders qty of 2 or up and go to cart, the qty shows up as **1** while the price is the amount of qty **2** or up.

For example, If i were to buy clothes quantity of **5** and press check out, when it brings me to the cart, the quantity is **1** while the price is the amount of quantity **5**. It also shows the quantity of **1** in the backend.

Is there any solution to this?

Thank you

Comment: did you try disabling that extension?

Answer (score 1):

I think that your controller doesn't get the qty parameter from your product during submitting.

To check that open your browser navigator then in `network tab` when you click on submit after select your quantity 3 for exemple, select the first line of this network tab, it looks like : `checkout/cat/add` after that you select the `parameters tab` in right side and see if you get the right `qyt="3"`, if no you have an issue in your form submitting, however if you get well the param with the right qty, now the next step is to check the value in your controller with this piece of code: `<?php var_dump ($this->getRequest()->getParams()); ?>` and check the qty value.

Don't forget if you ever need to make a change in a controller , think to rewrite it in **local** instead of **core**.

Comment: @Yong Park Please accept the answer if you found it helpful